# Background color does not change after cropping the image in cropperjs

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I use cropperjs to crop pictures.I want the background color of the cropped image to be white. Although I give fillColor as white, it still comes in black.

```js
 var cropper = $("#canvas1").cropper({
                    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                    strict: false,
                    guides: false,
                    dragCrop: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    mouseWheelZoom: false,
                    touchDragZomm: false,
                    autoCropArea: 0.5,
                    scalable: false,
                    cropBoxMovable: true,
                    cropBoxResizable: false,
                    setDragMode: 'crop',
                    minCanvasWidth: 25,
                    rotatable: true,
                    center: true,
                    modal: true,
                    viewMode: 0,
                    dragMode: 'move',
                    minContainerWidth: 200,
                    minContainerHeight: 100,
                    built: function () {
                        $(this).cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
                            fillColor: '#fff'
                        });
                    }
                })
```

I had tried the code below before. I got the "$(...).cropper.getCroppedCanvas is not a function" error in this too.

```js
$("#canvas1").cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
  fillColor: '#fff'
});
```

Comment: Please try setting `background: false` attribute in cropper.

Comment: I tried it, but it's still the same.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the server-side? If not, `$(this).cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {"fillColor": '#FFF'})` use this or `$("#canvas1").data('cropper').getCroppedCanvas()`

Comment: What problem can there be on the server side? I tried these too, but it didn't happen again.

Comment: on server-side if you are using plugins like intervention/image or any other similar then it's the issues with those plugins.